# Is there a way to convert integers to bools in go or vice versa?

Tags: types, go

Is there a builtin way to cast bools to integers or vice versa? I've tried normal casting, but since they use different underlying types, conversion isn't possible the classic way. I've poured over some of the specification, and I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: ` i != 0` to set an int to a bool. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546. `if` statement to set a bool to an integer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726854/12817546.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Int to bool is easy, just `x != 0` will do the trick. To go the other way, since Go doesn't support a ternary operator, you'd have to do:

```
var x int
if b {
    x = 1
} else {
    x = 0
}
```

You could of course put this in a function:

```
func Btoi(b bool) int {
    if b {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
 }
```

There are so many possible boolean interpretations of integers, none of them necessarily natural, that it sort of makes sense to have to say what you mean.

In my experience (YMMV), you don't have to do this often if you're writing good code. It's appealing sometimes to be able to write a mathematical expression based on a boolean, but your maintainers will thank you for avoiding it.

Comment: Note that the `else` in the first example is unnecessary as `x` will be initialized to `0`, as demonstrated in the answer by Cerise Limón.

Comment: This is absolutely not "a builtin way to cast", it is writing a boolean statement that checks whether a number is equal to 0.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a trick to convert from `int` to `bool`:

```
x := 0
newBool := x != 0 // returns false
```

where `x` is the `int` variable you want to convert from.

Comment: newBool := x != 0

Answer (score 11):

There are no [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `bool` to integer types or vice versa.

Use the inequality operator to convert integers to `bool` values:

```
b := i != 0
```

Use an if statement to convert a `bool` to an integer type:

```
var i int
if b {
    i = 1
}
```

Because the zero value for integer types is 0, the else branch shown in other answers is not necessary.

Comment: May as well just declare it... plus it is literally shorter `i := 0`

Answer (score 9):

```
var a int = 3
var b bool = a != 0
```

I just dropped this into the [demo box](http://golang.org/doc/play/) on the [golang front page](http://golang.org/):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 var a int = 3
 var b bool = a != 0
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界", b)
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 世界 true
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to show TMTOWTDT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bool2int(true))
    fmt.Println(bool2int(false))
}

func bool2int(a bool) uint64 {
    return *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))&1
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eULE6cJO_c0

Comment: Cool. Does this work across platforms? I mean, Go encodes the boolean as the least significant bit across platforms?

Comment: I think that on most (Intel) platforms we are little endian and the code above will work.  To make it more portable I guess that you could add a step to convert to Network order which is always big endian and then look at the other end of the bytes

Comment: If I see this in a company code, I will `git blame` it then report it to HR.

Comment: @jsgoupil haha yes, this way of doing it is a pretty bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

You could use maps:

```
package main

var (
   isZero = map[int]bool{0: true}
   intVal = map[bool]int{true: 1}
)

func main() {
   println(isZero[-2]) // false
   println(isZero[-1]) // false
   println(isZero[0]) // true
   println(isZero[1]) // false
   println(isZero[2]) // false
   
   println(intVal[false]) // 0
   println(intVal[true]) // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a numeric type from a bool, the `if` statement is the best you can do. See @MuffinTop very-good answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627381/12817546. This is also true for setting boolean and string types from a bool.

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    . "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var e []interface{}
    t := true
    if t {
        by := []byte{'G', 'o'}
        r := []rune{rune(by[0]), 111}
        f := 70.99
        s := Sprintf("%.f", f)
        i, _ := Atoi(s) // Atoi "ASCII to integer"
        bo := !(t == true)
        // var bo bool = t != true
        e = []interface{}{by[0], r[0], f, s, i, bo}
    }
    checkType(e)
}

func checkType(s []interface{}) {
    for k, _ := range s {
        // uint8 71, int32 71, float64 70.99, string 71, int 71, bool false
        Printf("%T %v\n", s[k], s[k])
    }
}
```

You can use `bo := !(t == true)` as @SamehShara said or `var bo bool = t != true` as @MattJoiner said to set a bool. Here `t` a bool with a value of `true` is set to `bo` a bool with a value of `false`.

To set a "true" or "false" string from a `true` or `false` bool use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", t)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413424/12817546. `strconv.ParseBool("true")` for the reverse. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53093945/12817546. Quotes edited.

Comment: A boolean, numeric, or string type can be set to another type. For`[]byte` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546, for `float64` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753031/12817546, `int` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546, `[]rune` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546, and for `string` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.