# how to convert bool to int8 in golang

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion

```
bitSet := true
var bitSetVar int8
```

How can I assign `bitSet` to `bitSetVar` as 1

I can do this:

```
if bitSet {
   bitSetVar = 1
} else {
   bitSetVar = 0
}
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: `if` statement to set a bool to another type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726854/12817546. `i != 0` to set an int for example to a bool. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546.

Comment: I guess golang language could add a feature like this https://github.com/golang/go/issues/63544, I guess is enought people ask for it, they will probably consider a change

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because the zero value for a `int8` is `0`, the else branch is not necessary.

```
bitSet := true
var bitSetVar int8
if bitSet {
   bitSetVar = 1
}
```

There are no [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `bool` to integer types. The if statement is the best you can do.

Answer (score 15):

yes this is the best way (fast and optimized):

```
bitSet := true
bitSetVar := int8(0)
if bitSet {
    bitSetVar = 1
}
```

using `var bitSetVar int8` or `bitSetVar := int8(0)` inside a function is the same, and you don't need `else` part, because the `bitSetVar` initialized with zero before that `if` statment.
while using `if` is OK (and fast) like this `B2i` function:

```
func B2i(b bool) int8 {
    if b {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

but you have another option using `map` too (not as fast as `if`, but nice and beautiful to show here):

```
var b2i = map[bool]int8{false: 0, true: 1}
```

like this working sample code (with commented outputs):

```
package main

import "fmt"

var b2i = map[bool]int8{false: 0, true: 1}

var i2b = []bool{false, true}

func B2i(b bool) int8 {
    if b {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(B2i(true))  // 1
    fmt.Println(B2i(false)) // 0

    fmt.Println(b2i[true])  // 1
    fmt.Println(b2i[false]) // 0

    fmt.Println(i2b[1]) // true
    fmt.Println(i2b[0]) // false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way currently is the best, because it's fast, with the same way you can convert int8 to bool, even easier. Also you can save 1 line:

```
var bitSetVar int8
if bitSet {
   bitSetVar = 1
}
```

Go community had an issue to implement this conversion, but seems that not all people are agree.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of memory efficiency, going by your approach of doing

```
if bitSet {
   bitSetVar = 1
} else {
   bitSetVar = 0
}
```

you are not using any extra variables to set your `bitSetVar`, hence I would say this is the best you could expect.

In terms of run-time, you are:

1. Checking the value of bitSet *once*, which is the least number of times you should be doing.
2. Setting the value of bitSetVar *once*, which you intend to do.

*Till now*, I would say you have been as efficient as you can be.

In terms of user readability, if you feel that this little snippet of code is making your code any less presentable, you could shift it into a function, maybe call it checkBitSetVar, like this:

```
func checkBitSetVar(mybool bool) int8{
    if mybool{
        return 1
    }
    return 0    //you just saved youself an else here!
}
```

and in the main, do:

```
setBitVar = checkBitSetVar(bitSet)
```

I think this is the best you can get out of Go.

Comment: Good answer. I especially like your use of the words "checking" and "setting". There are no "conversions" from the bool type. See @MuffinTop.