# convert a loop with inner conditon from python to go lang

Tags: python, go

im converting some code from python to go

here i want write equal code in go lang:

python :

```
while g_day_no >= g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 and leap):
    g_day_no -= g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 and leap)
    i+=1
```

my try:

```
leap := int32(1)
var i = int32(0)
for g_day_no >= (g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap)){
    g_day_no -= g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap)
    i+=1
}
```

but i have error in ide that say :

> Invalid operation: i == 1 && leap (mismatched types bool and int32)

for this section `(i == 1 && leap)`

how can i correct this part of my code?

Comment: I guess the operator precedence in Go is different; try `(i==1) && leap`

Comment: i tried still have error

Comment: Oh see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393933/is-there-a-way-to-convert-integers-to-bools-in-go-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is more strict about conditions. It requires booleans. `leap` is an integer, so just check the value:

`g_day_no >= (g_days_in_month[i] || (i == 1 && leap!=0))`

**More detailed answer**

Booleans (`True` and `False`) in Python correspond to the following integer values:

`True=>1`
`False=>0`

This can be seen with the following:

```
>>> True+0
1
>>> False+0
0
```

Therefore, when you have two booleans that are being added together, its the same as an `OR`:

```
True  + True  => 2 (True)
False + True  => 1 (True)
True  + False => 1 (True)
False + False => 0 (False)
```

This is the same "truth table" as OR:

True  OR True  => True
   False OR TRUE  => True
   True  OR False => True
   FALSE OR FALSE => False

Therefore, change your `+` to an `||` (`||` is `OR` in Go).

Comment: g_day_no >= g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap != 0)

still give me the error

```
Invalid operation: g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap != 0) (mismatched types int32 and bool)
```

Comment: what about
    g_day_no -= g_days_in_month[i] + (i == 1 && leap)

in inside of loop i did same thing but that dont work there

i did this : 

  g_day_no -= g_days_in_month[i] || (i == 1 && leap != 0)

Comment: You will have to take the conditional and move that to an if statement. If the condition is true, subtract 1 from `g_day_no`.